Writing down a well defined contraction for curvature tensor on boundary
Given the following Lemma:
\textbf{Lemma 5.1.1.} Let $M$, $N$ be compact manifolds with boundaries $\partial M$, $\partial N$ and Riemannian metrics $g$, $h$, respectively. Let $f: \partial M \to \partial N$ be a diffeomorphism.
The topological space $M \#_f N = M \cup_f N = M \cup_{x \sim f(x)} N$ admits the structure of a smooth manifold such that the inclusion maps $\partial M \hookrightarrow M \#_f N$ and $\partial N \hookrightarrow M \#_f N$ are embeddings. The image of the boundary has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to $M \times (-\epsilon, 0]$, where $M$ is identified with $M \times \{0\}$.
i)If $f^*(h|_{\partial N}) = g|_{\partial M}$, then the canonical metric $g \# h$ on $M \#_f N$ defined by $g \# h = g$ on $M$ and $g \# h = h$ on $N$ is well-defined and Lipschitz continuous.
ii)If additionally $f^*(\mathrm{II}_{\partial N}) = \mathrm{II}_{\partial M}$, then $g \# h$ is of class $C^{1,1}$.
iii) If additionally $f^*(R_{ N}(X, \nu_{\partial N}, \nu_{\partial N}, Z)) = R_M(X, \nu_{\partial M}, \nu_{\partial M}, Z)$, then $g \# h$ is of class $C^{2,1}$.
I dont understand the last expression in iii)
$$f^*(R_{ Q}(X, \nu_{\partial Q}, \nu_{\partial Q}, Z)) = R_M(X, \nu_{\partial M}, \nu_{\partial M}, Z)
$$
which does not seem well-defined,since f is a diffeo of the boundaries,How can i write down a well defined expression, which of the followng approches do i need?
$$
R_{\partial M}(Z,Y) = R_M(X, Z, Y, W)
$$
and then say that we need:
$$
f^*(R_{\partial Q}(\nu, \nu_{\partial Q})) = R_{\partial M}(\nu_{\partial M}, \nu_{\partial M}),
$$
or would it be more appropriate to say that:
$$
R_{\partial M}(X, Y) = R_M(X, \nu_{\partial M}, \nu_{\partial M}, Y),
$$
and then require that:
$$
f^*(R_{\partial Q}(X, Y)) = R_{\partial M}(X, Y)?
$$
I am confused can someone pls explain
